# Django Memcache : Compare and Set

Tags: python, django, caching, memcached

Over [here at the Django groups Tom Evans explains the method](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/a1631ef24b4db555/0e6c4e5478610fed?show_docid=0e6c4e5478610fed) to do ***compare and set*** in Django as shown below

```
You can access the memcached client via django though: 
>>> from django.core import cache 
>>> c=cache.get_cache('default') 
>>> help(c._client.cas)
```

But somehow I couldn’t get it to work.

```
>>> from django.core import cache
>>> c=cache.get_cache('memcache')
>>> help(c._client.cas)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MemcachedCache' object has no attribute '_client'
```

How can I get to do a ***compare and set in Django***, if not the method shown above?

I use Django version 1.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after looking at the source code! i find this at BaseMemcachedCache:

```
@property
def _cache(self):
    """
    Implements transparent thread-safe access to a memcached client.
    """
    if getattr(self, '_client', None) is None:
        self._client = self._lib.Client(self._servers)

    return self._client
```

So, I would say that, this will work:

```
c._cache.cas
```

Try, and let me know!

for more details: https://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/django/core/cache/backends/memcached.py