# compare and set using cache in django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, caching

I came across a video which explains problems of multiple users overwriting the cache at same time.The speaker suggests using compare and set to counter this (http://www.udacity.com/wiki/CS253%20Unit%206?course=cs253#cas).

He mentions two methods

```
gets(key) → value, unique
cas(key, value, unique) → True/False

from google.appengine.api import memcache

val, unique = memcache.gets(key)
r = memcache.cas(key, newval, unique)
while r == False:
    unique, val = memcache.gets(key)
    r = memcache.cas(key, newval, unique)
```

Is something like this available in `django cache`? or is this `googleappengine` specific? .Can someone suggest how this can be done using `django cache`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? You should paraphrase the video here, and link it. It's extremely likely that you'd be using memcached on GAE and elsewhere, so the same facilities will be available, but without some more info it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the generic Django caching framework, this is not possible. If you are only using MemCache, [this question on Django Memcache: Compare and Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917604/django-memcache-compare-and-set) contains all you need.

However, be advised that while CAS solves the problem of multiple users setting the same cache value, this is only a problem in  high traffic environments. If simultaneous cache-miss-and-updates occur once or twice per month, you'd be better off ignoring CAS.

If the cached value is *really* expensive to calculate, you could also think of a separate background task that calculates the result, stores it in the cache, and runs just before the cache expiry. In this case, your users would never experience a cache miss and the entire CAS-issue becomes irrelevant.